# Update cached data using rxjs publishReplay: Angular 5

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a list of users that I want to cache so that different component in my Angular 5 app does not hit the web service, and rather return cached response. To do this I did the following:

```
getAllUsers() {
  return this.getUncachedUsersList().publishReplay().refCount();
}

getUncachedUsersList() {
  return this.http.get('https://......');
}
```

In the above code snippet, I have two methods. I call getAllUsers inside all the components that needs users list, except in the case where let say I am adding a user and then I need an updated list. In that case I call 'getUncachedUsersList' to get the latest.

The problem is, when I call 'getUncachedUsersList', I expect 'getAllUsers' to cache the new list, but instead it return the same old list that was cached before adding a new user. So I would like to know how can I clear the cached response and save the new response that I get from 'getUncachedUsersList' and return the new response when 'getAllUsers' is called.

Comment: In your case `getAllUsers()` is not actually cache-ing data. If you call that method twice and subscribe both, you will see 2 network calls fired. You need to store `Observable` reference someway. By the way t7yang-s answer will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Rathar than doing like this, you should considering maintain a cacheable `Subject`.

```
// behavior subject do cache the latest result
// each subscribe to userList$ get the latest
userList$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);

// each time getNewUserList get call
// userList$ get the new list by calling next
getNewUserList() {
  this.http.get(`http://...`).subscribe(list => this.userList$.next(list));
}
```